# JQuery-UI: How to build a Inventory using Accordion + Sortable? Limiting Sortable & Removing Scroll

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion, jquery-ui-sortable, inventory

I'm trying to build an inventory using Accordion and Sortable via JQuery UI.

---

**Goal / Features:** - here is what I'd like to have this do:

1. **Limiting Sortables** - an item from one accordion CANNOT be placed back in another grouping (though I might allow an X to just delete it from the list on the bottom)
2. **Removing Horizontal Scroll** - Right now when I'm doing this in my own code (though not in my jsfiddle version below) and I drag something to the side, it sometimes causes the accordion div to scroll horizontally endlessly. I've tried limiting the scroll sideways using overflow-x: hidden; but that didn't work either. This happens when I utilize jqueryui.com/demos/demos.css in my server file which I can't seem to get to work in jsfiddle so my apologies if this isn't something anyone can see working there. You can, however, see the bug (sort of) here: jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists if you try to drag one of them far to the right.

**Current version (jsfiddle):** - Here is my current version:
http://jsfiddle.net/theredknight/XZkaF/3/

---

**Source Files/Links:**
The original concept from here: 
jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/connect-lists.html

I've tried the following to no effect:

- [jQuery UI: Drag Sortable from within Accordion to Outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320285/jquery-ui-drag-sortable-from-within-accordion-to-outside)
- [jquery sortable cannot be dragged outside of accordion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040359/jquery-sortable-cannot-be-dragged-outside-of-accordion)
- [jQuery-Ui: Cannot drag object outside of an accordion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827504/jquery-ui-cannot-drag-object-outside-of-an-accordion)

---

**Similar Working Version:**
Here is a version someone wrote which is similar, but s/he seems to have modified the jquery ui libraries and I couldn't get it to look as nice as I was hoping for:

[Accordion plus Sortable](http://www.telecable.es/personales/covam1/deployToNenyures/SourceCode/jQuery/accordion/accordion.htm)

Thank you kindly!
~trk