# Dragging an element outside of accordion menu in jquery with draggable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-accordion

i have been struggling with these problem all today.
i added a draggable object inside a jquery accordion menu.
the problem is it doesnt allow me to drag it outside.
when i try to drag it outside it is resizing the div inside accordion menu and showing scrollbar.
here i made a demo of the problem.
http://jsbin.com/efoje4/4

please help :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your `draggable` declaration, add the option `appendTo:'body'`

working example: http://jsbin.com/efoje4/6

see [jQuery-Ui: Cannot drag object outside of an accordion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827504/jquery-ui-cannot-drag-object-outside-of-an-accordion)

Comment: Beat me to it, I wondered why my revision number was so high.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsbin.com/efoje4/8/

You can use appendTo: 'body' which binds to object to the body of the page and not the current container element.